# Ограничение текста в ширину

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую. Интересует такой вопрос:

Есть текстовый input, текст в нем не должен превышать 180px в ширину, при превышении лишние символы удаляются. Как лучше всего реализовать, какие есть варианты, может уже есть что-то готовое?

Для себя отметил пока вариант с блоком-dummy, где скрытому блоку будет передаваться текст, затем смотреть его ширину и циклично удалять последние символы до достижения необходимой ширины.

Comment: Другого способа, вроде бы, и нет

Comment: другой способ - textarea

Comment: @Elena У textarea просто переход на другую строку, для меня такой вариант не удобен, мне нужна именно одна строка меньше 180px.

Comment: @Happy_Cougar, ага прошу прощения не так поняла

Answer (score 0):

```
text-overflow: clip | ellipsis
```

Должно помочь

Comment: Что-то не то... Вроде другое просят.